# Having some trouble getting a couple of "wildcard" expressions to work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

Ive been working through the w3schools website and have found it very helpful, however a couple of problems have been giving me trouble.

[Here is the table for both pieces of syntax]

[image: 1]

Both of these pieces of syntax appear to be incorrectly returning "empty set". The syntax is below. Any advice is appreciated!

Syntax 1

```
select * from Student where Surname like '[!acf]%';
```

Syntax 2

```
select * from Student where Name like '[a-f]%';
```

Comment: You are not using MySQL-compatible like patterns.

Comment: Those patterns are a non-standard extension available in SQL Server only, not MySQL.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what the equivalent is in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the SQL Server patterns mean.

If the first query searches for students whose surnames don't start with 'a', 'c', or 'f' then in MySQL you can use a *standard regular expression* for it, as in:

```
select * from student where surname regexp '[^acf].*';
```

If the second query searches for students whose names do start with any letter between 'a' and 'f' (both lower case) then the regular expression can be:

```
select * from student where name regexp '[a-f].*';
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s6NqtmvoHvxSsufeMAoQSJ/0).